# Pydev Data Type hint for Class members

Tags: python, comments, intellisense, pydev

According to pydev manual, one can provide type hints for variables using comments
http://pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

I am trying to inform pydev about type of class members (so that code completion and intellisense can work properly).

Here is what I have tried:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=None
        self.b=None

    def setVariable(self,a,b)
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

    def doSomething(self):
        ': :type self.a: packageX.moduleY.ClassZ'
        # use self.a from here on
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Pydev (3.4.1) doesn't support docstring-type-hinting for class attributes, as well as propagation of type-hinted variables into class attributes.

Here's an example I'd expect to work:
(Given this class, I expect for completion suggestions in the last two lines of the example code, for the reasons mentioned in the comments on these lines.)

```
class SampleClass(object):
    """Summary of class here.

    Attributes:
        member: Member
        @type member: MemberClass
        other_member: Another member
    """

    def __init__(self, other=None):
        """Inits SampleClass with blah.

        Args:
            @param other: Instance of OtherMemberClass
            @type other: OtherMemberClass
        """
        self.other_member = other
        self.member = None

    def public_method(self):
        """Performs operation blah."""
        self.member.#should get completions from MemberClass here because hinted in class docstring
        self.other_member.#should get completions from OtherMemberClass here because `other` was assigned to attribute in __init__, and `other` type was hinted in __init__ docstring.
```

I [opened a ticket](https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/384) on the Pydev tracker regrading this.

Comment: Pydev versions 2.8.0 onwards are supposed to support comment-based type hinting.  Unfortunately, in 2020, 6 years after appearance of PEP-484, even Pydev 4.0 does not support that style of type hints.